# php mysql error for creating a table

Tags: php, mysql, create-table

I got an error while creating a table in php with mysql database, and I tried testing directly on mysql query engine it works fine. whereas in php code it gives below error

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near.

Below is the code I am writing

```
$query14 = mysql_query("create table $tablename (
                                           project_id INT,
                                           project_client_id INT, 
                                           project_partner_id INT, 
                                           project_manager_id INT,
                                           project_employees INT, 
                                           project_name VARCHAR(500), 
                                           project_status TEXT,
                                           project_summary LONGTEXT, 
                                           project_order INT, 
                                           project_start_date DATETIME,
                                           project_end_date DATETIME
                                         ) ENGINE = INNODB;");
```

and below is the image attached and table structure should be and this is the sample table i create using with phpmyadmin interface.
And below is the full error

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''8' (project_id INT, project_client_id INT, project_partner_id INT, project_mana' at line 1`
```

[image]

Comment: What is $tablename at the time you execute this?

Comment: i think $tablename with work with '$tablename'??

Comment: @MarcB and @jogesh_p : $tablename value is dynamic, it changes with some id and its working fine.. And even i change it to '$tablename', but doesnt work out.. And my $tablename has a value and i have `echoed it`

Comment: @Rafee: can you give us an example on how `$tablename` looks like? And are you sure that this is the query which fails? Btw. The quoted version is more like `\`$tablename\`` (hope that looks right, since it's also the SO-inline-code-character)

Comment: @raffe: `create table '$tablename' ...` would be a syntax error. Field/table names cannot be quoted like that - it turns them into strings, not field/table names. What is the FULL error message you get, especially the part after `...to use near:`: that's the important/critical part.

Comment: @MarcB I have added the updated error in question and `$tablname` = `8`

Comment: There you go. You're trying to create a table whose name is (string)8. This is not a legitimate table name in MySQL. Table names MUST begin with an alphabet character, not a digit. And using `'8'` is double invalid. It's an integer being cast as a string being used as a table name. Table names CANNOT be specified using string notations, so there's your syntax error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I didn't see any problem with your query. But what is the value of `$tablename`? Two error possibilities here :

1. The variable `$tablename` is empty.
2. `$tablename` is a key-word.

Please check the above two otherwise its all right.

**UPDATE :**

As per your updated question please try with the following code. I think it will help you.

```
$query14 = mysql_query("create table `$tablename` (
                                           `project_id` INT,
                                           `project_client_id` INT, 
                                           `project_partner_id` INT, 
                                           `project_manager_id` INT,
                                           `project_employees` INT, 
                                           `project_name` VARCHAR(500), 
                                           `project_status` TEXT,
                                           `project_summary` LONGTEXT, 
                                           `project_order` INT, 
                                           `project_start_date` DATETIME,
                                           `project_end_date` DATETIME
                                         ) ENGINE = INNODB;");
```

Comment: `$tablename` is not empty and if `$tablename` is a keyword then i have change that to `$tablename1` but still it doesnt run.

Comment: please mention your table name. what is your table name?

Comment: See `$tablename` is generated dynamically from other database, at present i am exprimenting this and found out that `$tablename` = `8` and I will update the question with more error

Answer (score 1):

Your query syntax is fine, it looks like $tablename is empty.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is what is getting replaced for $tablename.

Having the full code example would be more useful in debugging the error.

The mysql create statement works just fine here on mysql 5.1.58 .

Answer (score 0):

As you said in above comments that after echoing the `$tablename` you got the value `8` then it is not possible to create table.

you have to rename the value of `$tablename` like `tbl_8`.

remember with the name `tbl-8` your also got error,,

Comment: yeah!, i changed to `$tablename` = "project_" . $someid, and got error with `right syntax to use near ''project_8' (project_id INT, project_client_id INT, project_partner_id INT, proj' at line 1`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, $tablename is 8 currently and for SQL table, table name must start with a letter. Current tablename is invalid.